# What happens if my cat loses the election?

Tags: politicats

My cat has won all of the elections I have entered so far. But there is a possibility at some point, he will lose an election. Does this work like Clicker Heroes and just mean I go back to the "fighting enemies" bit until my cat has enough votes that I can have a good chance of winning the election? Or is there some sort of penalty?

Comment: What's politicats?

Comment: @Alex a Clicker Heroes sort of game on Android.

Comment: @Ash it's on iOS now as well.

Comment: @Micoxion oh, I'll have to check it out, seems cool

Answer (score 5):

It says "Election Lost", stays on the same level and allows you to hold a new election whenever you want, similar to clicker heroes.

[image: "ELECTION LOST" text and "Hold Election" button]